# Where can I find the Matroska Container "Real" Specification?

Tags: c#, mkv, matroska

I know this sounds like a simple question, but I just wasted the last 30 minutes looking for where I can find this "real" container specification that the Matroska site hints to. I'm trying to write a simple C# demuxer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather there is none since the format was derived from MCF and extended via EBML... it is a "work in progress" IMO - [thus only draft specs exist AFAIK](http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html#track). Follow the link and you will find a lot of information including all you need to write a demuxer...

Comment: I'm following your logic here(the link you posted is where I went first), but I did find on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) that CoreCodec owns the copyrights and trademarks of the MKV Specification. So I was thinking that they were out there somewhere. I guess I also question how Android, FFMPEG, and VLC wrote encoder/decoders without a common specification. But maybe your correct.

Comment: @shibbybird several application use libmatroska which is built based on the "darft specs" behing that link...

Comment: Yes I'm thinking that your right on that. Looks like everyone is using libmatroska. I just checked out the libmatroska code and am going to use that as my "specification" thanks.